# root n consistency of parameter in mixture distribution

Tags: distributions, self-study, maximum-likelihood, central-limit-theorem, consistency

We have iid observations $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ from CDF $\theta G + (1- \theta)H$ where $\theta \in (0,1)$ is unknown. Find a $\sqrt{n}$ consistent estimator for $\theta$ using the observations. Note that here, $G,H$ are known distribution functions.

I tried using mle, but it need not exist. Also, we do not know anything about finiteness of the moments of $G,H$ so that rules out clt based approaches ig.

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag and read its wiki.

Comment: Why do you say the MLE need not exist? It seems to me that it should, at least for large enough $n$ (though it might converge faster than $\sqrt{n}$, eg, if $G$ and $H$ aren't mutually absolutely continuous)

Comment: @ThomasLumley , I recalled that mle did not exist in the case of gaussian mixtures as the likelihood has no upper bound in that case. But I need to recheck that.

Comment: That's when $\sigma^2$ has to be estimated, since it can go to zero to get perfect fit at one point.  I don't think there's a problem when $G$ and $H$ are known distributions

Comment: Ok, thank you for correcting me !

Comment: It is a rather contradictory statement to say "$G,H$ are known distribution functions", and then state "we do not know whether their moments are finite". In what sense then they are known distributions?

Answer (score 0):

Assume $G\ne H$, so that $\theta$ is identifiable.

If we assume finite means $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ of $G$ and $H$ respectively, then $E(X_1)$ is finite and is given by $E(X_1)=\theta \mu_1+(1-\theta)\mu_2$. Now the sample mean $\overline X_n$ is a consistent estimator of $E(X_1)$, based on which you can find a method of moment estimator of $\theta$ provided $\mu_1\ne \mu_2$. For $\sqrt n$-consistency of this estimator, you would also require finiteness of variance of $X_1$.

Alternatively, suppose $c$ is any real number for which $G(c)\ne H(c)$. Then a consistent estimator of $\theta G(c)+(1-\theta)H(c)$ is the empirical distribution function $\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n I(X_i\le c)$. This yields another estimator of $\theta$ which can be used when $E(X_1)$ does not exist or when $E(X_1)$ does exist but $\mu_1=\mu_2$.